# Why array_shift on an array with an empty string breaks the loop?

Tags: php, loops, for-loop, while-loop

I just noticed that iterating an array using a while and array_shift behaves differently from a simple for loop when encounters an empty string. Here's a sample:

While loop:

```
$arr=[1, "",1,""];
while ($elm = array_shift($arr))
{
    var_dump($elm);
}
```

For loop:

```
$arr=[1, "",1,""];
for ($i = 0; $i<count($arr); $i++)
{
    var_dump($arr[$i]);
}
die();
```

Why does the while exit the loop?

Comment: because the expression evaluates to false ?

Comment: https://3v4l.org/h94FE

Comment: to make while loop keep running, Its must to provide `true` value in `while()`. In first array, you second value is `null`, Which consider as `false` OR `0` value. Hence while loop getting stop.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because an empty string is a **falsy** value in PHP:

> var_dump((bool) "");        // bool(false)

[The PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php)

To make the first example work with empty strings you should check against `array_shift` returning **NULL**:

```
$arr = [1, "", 1, ""];
while (($elm = array_shift($arr)) !== NULL) {
    var_dump($elm);
}
```

**Explanation**

`array_shift` removes the first element from the array and returns its value:

```
$arr = [1, ""];
array_shift($arr); // we get 1
array_shift($arr); // we get ""
array_shift($arr); // we get NULL because the array is empty now
```

In your first example you have `while ($elm = array_shift($arr))` which means:

- remove the first element and save its value inside `$elm`
- interpret `$elm` as a boolean (this is done implicitly) and only continue if it evaluates to **TRUE**.

Let's manually go through each iteration to make it more clear:

- first iteration: `while ($elm = 1)` -> `while (true)` because 1 is truthy. **We continue the loop**.
- second iteration: `while ($elm = "")` -> `while (false)` because an empty string is falsy. **We exit the loop**.

Comment: For clarity, it's `$elm = array_shift($arr)` is equivalent to `$elm = ""` which is evaluated by the left-side variable value set in the operation, e.g., `""`, which evaluates to falsey.

Comment: I guess that performance-wise, the for loop it's better than the while plus null test, correct?

Comment: @sabas Definitely. `array_shift` changes the original array (which takes additional time), the for loop doesn't: `$arr = [1,2,3]; array_shift($arr);array_shift($arr);array_shift($arr); var_dump($arr);` outputs an empty array.

Answer (score 2):

Because the empty string evaluates to false

Answer (score 1):

Because the **second value of your array is empty string** which converts to bool false

Try to use another array and everything will be good:

```
$arr=[1, "non-empty value", 1, "another non-empty value"];
while ($elm = array_shift($arr))
{
    var_dump($elm);
    echo '<br>'; // this is bonus ;)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solutions proposed by others are still prone to error if an array contains a `null`. If it's really necessary to modify the array rather than do a simple `foreach`, a robust way to construct this would be:

```php
while ($arr)
{
    $elm = array_shift($arr)
    var_dump($elm);
}
```

This is because arrays are always truthy unless they're empty, regardless of what values they contain.